# Strippig comma and hyphen from a string

Tags: javascript

I have been looking at a lot of forum posts but I can't seem to get it to work. My string I want stripped is: 2050,-

I want it to be 2050

The code for stripping i use atm. is:

```
<script>
var pris = '{{total}}';
  pris = pris.replace(/[^\d,]/g, '');

  fbq('track', 'Purchase', {
    value: pris,
  currency:'DKK',
  content_ids: '0', 
  content_type: 'product'
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
pris = pris.replace(/[^\d,]/g, '');
```

to (remove the , from the regex char class)

```
pris = pris.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
```

and you should be happy

```js
var pris = '2050,-';
console.log('Before: ' + pris);

pris = pris.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
console.log('After: ' + pris);
```

Comment: I'm using this to trip a dynamic output on a website, via google tag manager. I have tried both: 

(/[^\d,]/g, '');
(/[^\d]/g, '');

And google tag manager still gives me a 2050,- output

Comment: I updated the answer so you can clearly see it works. If you still have the issue of seeing it with ',-' suffix then it is another problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var x="2050,-"
x=x.replace(',', '').replace('-', '') //"2050"
```